# Remove redundant html tags from string

Tags: c#, html, string

I various **string** objects with **html** formatted text. Some of these strings contain certain tags at the end that I want to remove programmatically, like these **linebreak** and **paragraph** tags at the end:

```
<li><ol>  **Text/List**  </li></ol><p><br></p><br><br>
```

I need to check the string from its endpoint, but I can't figure out where to cut the end off, or where to look for the cutting point. I just need to get rid of these redundant tags.

I tried to build a function that checks the string, I know it doesn't work properly, but it's my basis:

```
public static String RemoveRedundantTags(this String baseString, String html)
    {
        if (html.Contains("<"))
        {
            for (Int32 i = html.Length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                if (html[i] == '<' && html[i - 1] != '>' && html[i + 1] != '/')
                {
                    redundantTags = html.Substring(html[i], html.Length - i);

                    html = html.Replace(redundantTags, String.Empty);

                    return html;
                }
            }
        }

        return html;
    }
```

Comment: If you don't say any condition, there is no way to help you. The easier way is to remove all of the HTML tags and leave only the text.

Comment: What means redundant? What makes them redundant? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I get them from the TFS, and they are left over tags when someone creating the whole thing made a few line breaks and didn't delete them. They create empty space in my output. I need the other html tags, because the whole thing is inserted into Word.

Comment: What about `htmlstring.Replace("<br>","").Replace("<p>","").Replace("</p>","");` or something like that?

Comment: That would remove every paragraph and every linebreak in the whole string though, these types of tags are not generally redundant, just the ones at the end that have no actual content.

Comment: Can't you just remove all those tags and after that add what you need? I don't know what do you consider redundant,but it seems easier to me.

Comment: They need to be removed from every html string that has them, and there will be a lot. How would I cut them off? Is it even possible without a specific condition? Maybe somehow check if there is content between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'd need to manipulate HTML, i'd use a HTML-parser like [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), **not** [string methods or regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Here is an example that removes all `br` from the end:

```
string html = "<li><ol>  **Text/List**  </li></ol><p><br></p><br><br>";
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var brToRemove = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Reverse().TakeWhile(n => n.Name == "br");
foreach (HtmlNode node in brToRemove)
    node.Remove();

using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    doc.Save(writer);
    string result = writer.ToString();
}
```

The result is:

```
<li><ol>  **Text/List**  </ol></li><p>
```

As you can see by default it fixes parse errors by itself. There was one:

> Start tag `<ol>` was not found

---

If the html was

```
html = "<ol><li>TEXT</li></ol><p><br></p><p><br></p>&nbsp;";
```

and you wanted to remove all `<p>` and `<br>` tags but also the `&nbsp;` from the end as commented. You could use following approach that uses a dictionary where the key is the tag-name and the value are the strings of the inner-text of this tag, so a sub-selector. If the value is an empty sequence the tag should be removed no matter what inner-text it has. Here is a dictionary for your requirement:

```
var tagsToRemove = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
{
    { "br", Enumerable.Empty<string>() }, { "p", Enumerable.Empty<string>() }, { "#text", new[] { "&nbsp;" } }
};
```

Now the LINQ query to find all tags to remove is:

```
var brToRemove = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
    .Reverse()
    .TakeWhile(n => tagsToRemove.ContainsKey(n.Name) 
                 && tagsToRemove[n.Name].DefaultIfEmpty(n.InnerText).Contains(n.InnerText));
```

The (desired) result is:

```
<ol><li>TEXT</li></ol>
```

Comment: That works for this specific string, thank you, it's much more than I have now, but where it doesn't work is for this string:

Comment: TEXT</li></ol><p><br></p><p><br></p>&nbsp;

Comment: @tweedledum11: what is the desired result?

Comment: The desired result would be that there is text and used html tags (like li and ol in this example) without these linebreaking and paragraph tags that are at the end of the actual content. They are leftovers that I don't want in the resulting output.

Comment: @tweedledum11: but that isn't valid html anyway, the `li` and `ol` tags have no start tag. If you wanted to remove the `&nbsp;` and the `<br>` + `<p>` tags the only valid html remaining was `"TEXT"`. Do you want to keep that invalid html or do you also want to remove it?

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion now. What I posted as examples are just excerpts of the full strings. This is just what the end of the html string looks like. I validate the html in  another part of my project, so the html is correct. I just want to get rid of those redundant leftover tags.

Comment: Thank you so much for the new input, this looks much better and actually works for the example I brought. Now the problem with having so many items that there are variations. For example, I now have this at the end of an html string: TEXT.<br></span></li></ul><p><span style="font-style:italic;"><br></span></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><em></em> , and it stays exactly like this for some reason. Do I need to add variables for every possible tag? If so, shouldn't the br and p tags be removed at least?